# Assess whether the generated data follows the distribution

Tags: density-function, random-generation, cumulative-distribution-function, histogram, rayleigh-distribution

Using the Inverse function method I managed to  draw a sample of 500 random data from a Cumulative distribution function. $f(x)$,$F(x)$ and $F_X^{-1}(u)$ are as follows:

$$f_X=\frac{x}{5}exp\left({\frac{-x^2}{10}}\right)$$
$$F_X=1-exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{10}\right)$$
$$F_X^{-1}=\sqrt{-10log{\left(1-u\right)}}$$

The R code:

```
n<- 500
u<- runif(n)
x<- (10*log(1/(1-u)))^(1/2)
hist(x, prob = TRUE) # density histogram of sample
y<- seq(0, 10, 0.01)
lines(y, {y/5*exp(-y^2/10)}) # density curve
```

and the random histogram generated:
[image]

And the question I am asking, or rather my lecturer is:

"Assess whether the generated data follows a Rayleigh distribution in question"

I want to say it does, because the curve fits the histogram nicely. But it is a very generic explanation. Could you analyse this in more depth for me please? I am not sure what to say. Thank you.

EDIT: ATTEMPT.

$H_0:$ Data follows our distribution

$H_1:$ Data doesn't follow our distribution

```
g<-function(x){1-exp(-x^2/10)}
ks.test(u, g)

One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  u
D = 0.90512, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Since p<0.05 we reject the null hypothesis

Comment: See threads on [chi squared goodness of fit tests](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=chi+squared+goodness+of+fit+test).

Comment: I found a kolmogorov smirnoff test. Wouldn't it be better? But I am not sure how to interpret it.

Comment: In your case, both tests will work fine because you can generate lots of data.  Interpreting the KS result is no different than interpreting any other hypothesis test.

Comment: Could you look at my edit and tell me if I interpreted the test correctly? Also am i correct in assuming that r using $\alpha=0.05$ by default? Thank you for help.

Comment: Everything worked beautifully.  You tested whether the *uniform* variates you drew and stored in `u` have a Rayleigh distribution and the KS test gave convincing evidence they do not.  The relevant test for your question is conducted with the command `ks.test(x,g)`.

Comment: I see! Thank You very much good sir. After running the correct version of the test D is small and p is big. Have a lovely day!